# Change date in docker container

Tags: docker, date

When i create a `new Date()` in my back-end the date is in UTC±00:00 format.

I need the UTC-3 format. I tried some things like [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/change-time-in-docker-container/#:%7E:text=To%20know%20the%20current%20time,date%27%20command%20can%20be%20used.&text=To%20know%20the%20timezone%20configured,file%20has%20to%20be%20checked.) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes), but no working.

Wen i type `docker exec -it 68856c74974a date` i have :

> Mon Jun 22 17:15:22 UTC 2020

And i need :

> Mon 22 Jun 14:15:22 -03

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu                  latest              74435f89ab78        5 days ago          73.9MB
playcode-runner_front   latest              e53bf65cc234        2 weeks ago         1.44GB
playcode-runner_api     latest              be1e67561898        2 weeks ago         186MB
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   latest              6f9550cff175        3 weeks ago         469MB
hello-world             latest              bf756fb1ae65        5 months ago        13.3kB
node                    10.14.2             8a752d5af4ce        18 months ago       894MB
mysql                   8.0.3               00400babc1b7        2 years ago         343MB
anapsix/alpine-java     jdk8                ed55c27d366d        3 years ago         171MB
```

And:

```
$ docker image inspect playcode-runner_api
```

Only a part:

```
"Architecture": "amd64",
"Os": "linux",
"Size": 185505062,
"VirtualSize": 185505062,
```

Comment: which base image are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure. Ubuntu. I'm going to put the commands that led me to this and you guys giggle if it's the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the TZ variable works for me:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -e TZ=UTC ubuntu date -R
Thu, 25 Jun 2020 14:17:30 +0000

$ docker run -it --rm -e TZ=UTC-3 ubuntu date -R
Thu, 25 Jun 2020 17:17:32 +0300
```

With `docker exec`, it gets the environment from when you start the container, so you'll need to recreate the container with the desired environment:

```
$ docker run -d --rm -e TZ=UTC --name utc ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
8abcb471c2fb7c933bbdabd629e0d1d08cd926017ee5f7ccf7d54337d1fd4460

$ docker run -d --rm -e TZ=UTC-3 --name utc-3 ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
670336f127097a1c9f488a086dfd40496be433a7434dd9a3ac38feaaaabbb5db

$ docker exec utc date -R
Fri, 26 Jun 2020 00:08:52 +0000

$ docker exec utc-3 date -R
Fri, 26 Jun 2020 03:08:59 +0300
```

Comment: When I type `docker run -it --rm -e TZ=UTC+3 playcode-runner_api date -R` i have `Thu, 25 Jun 2020 19:23:33 -0300`like i want. But if i type `docker exec -it 172338d6a229 date` I have wrong date.

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota Please provide all the steps that someone could run to reproduce your scenario in your question, similar to how I've done in my answer above.

Comment: Excuse me. I tested it again and it's working. But it seems that I create new containers and the old ones still exist. So when I did a test on my app, the wrong value appeared in the database.

Comment: Now i need delete the old containers and create a new image. But this solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to make your own Dockerfile, FROM the image you are currently using, and add ([as in here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212562/5470)):

```
USER theRightUser
RUN echo "alias date='date -Is'>>~/.bashrc"
```

That would then use ISO-8601 for displaying the date like:

```
2020-06-24T22:04:10+02:00
```

Comment: theRightUser is my user in my pc ?

Comment: @ThiagoSoaresMota The user used by the base image: you need to refer to its own Dockerfile to see what user is used there. It won't be the one from your PC, since Docker defines a container which isolates its execution environment from the host (your PC): by its very nature, its user is internal to the container.